# Web config throws error after publish HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I've developed a project using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and have run into an issue where the `web.config` duplicates the `system.webServer` on publishing in another machine.

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Project.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\Project.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Config Error**

*Config section 'system.webServer/aspNetCore' already defined. Sections must only appear once per config file. See the help topic  for exceptions*

**Publish Profile**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>GUID</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>false</_IsPortable>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>RemoteMachine</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>Project</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName />
    <_SavePWD>False</_SavePWD>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If I publish straight from Visual Studio it works fine and the `web.config` does not change but I'm using TeamCity to build and publish the project. Obviously removing the extra `system.webServer` fixes it but I'm sure there is a root cause to this. Am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: Iis as a server and the applications (sites) it runs can each have their own configs and they're loadednin a hierarchy from root(machine level) to tip(site/for/virtual app). If a section is defined in the machine config it becomes common to all sites. If a site then also defines it a config error can arise. Remove the section from whichever config you want depending on whether other sites require it. There's a way of getting iis to list all the web configs it has loaded for a particular site but I forget how to show it

Comment: @prd Yes I know that will fix it as mentioned but that means every time I publish from TeamCity I would have to remove that element. I want to figure out why it is duplicating it so I can solve the problem without having to remove it manually.

Comment: you can ignore `web.config` file during deployment to avoid the issue

Comment: @Saif How can I do this?

Comment: Team city must be getting it's config from somewhere - so where is that?. Perhaps it does web config transforms and you can use this mechanism to remove the section from the release config but keep other sections, and possibly keep the section for debug config

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for the reply. If I remove the config will it save these changes for future publishes?

Comment: I've never used teamcity, but octopus deploy can be configured to carry out web confirm transformations. I'd be amazed if a build and deploy system didn't support them - maybe google for how to do them in TC?

Comment: @CaiusJard The config is generated on publishing from the other machine. TeamCity just carries out the command to publish on that machine. I will check the IIS configs you mentioned and see.